# object.hide() is not hiding the full kinetic body in Godot

Tags: game-engine, godot, gdscript

I'm trying to code a game in Godot 3 where my character can collect certain objects. The moment the character collects them - i.e collides with them, the object disappears and gets added to an array.

While doing this, I have successfully managed to make the object disappear, but somehow the area around which the object existed is still not walkable - in the sense, the collision object of the kinematic body object is somehow still functioning and I don't want it to still be there.

This GIF explains the problem:

[Problem GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIRuN.jpg)

Code for collision -

```
for body in $hitbox.get_overlapping_bodies():
    if(body.get("type")!= "prota"):
        if body.get("type")=="ingredient":
            inventory.add_to_inventory(body, body.get("type"), "collect")
```

Inventory.add_to_inventory function -

```
func add_to_inventory(the_item, item_type, cause):
    if item_type=="ingredient":
        if cause=="collect":
            inventory_ingredients.append(the_item)
            the_item.hide()
```

The above snipped appends the item into my array as required. It also hides the object but the collision object is still there.

Structure of the collision object (Pineapple):

[image]

Placement of objects on my LevelL

[image]

The Sprite's texture is loaded using code and is not manually added.

```
get_node("Pineapple").get_node("Display").set_texture(pineapple)
```

Any help regarding this will be appreciated. I am willing to provide more details if needed. I have very little background in coding and I might have made rookie mistakes too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hide` only makes the `Node` and its children invisible, it does not change the physics behavior in any way. If you want to get rid of the object completely, call [`Node.queue_free`](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_node.html#class-node-method-queue-free). If you want the `Node` to persist, but not cause collisions, you could set [`disabled`](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_collisionshape.html#class-collisionshape-property-disabled) on the `CollisionShape`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was very clear and I learned something new.

Comment: Note I mistakenly said `free`, but I meant `queue_free` (edited now). You almost always want to use `queue_free` instead of free, see the linked docs for more info.

Comment: Using the function "disabled" worked for me. I did check both queue_free and free but somehow they're deleting the existence of the object even in the array that I added them to. How do I prevent that while using queue_free?

Comment: You don't. Only use `queue_free` if you want to get rid of the object completely. In some cases that is what you want.